# How to clone new group of fields with and increment the name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, javascript-objects

I have problem when i'm trying  to copy a group of fields.

for example I have

```
<div class="must_Duplicated ">
<div class="form-group">
    <label >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="study[0].name" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Middle:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="study[0].Middle"  >
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Surname:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="study[0].surname"  >
</div>
</div>
```

What i need is to duplicate 'must_Duplicated' class when i click on something

but the idea is to increment

```
study[0].name
study[0].Middle
study[0].surname
```

to

```
study[1].name
study[1].Middle
study[1].surname
```

and so on

I have tried a lot of ways  but I couldn't find a solution to increment the value of name in each time

what is above is only an example my code is longer than this

Comment: I don't think that you can do such thing like auto increment, array without programming language.

Comment: i can do it in angularjs but I dont need to go inside angular for only one thing

Comment: I think you want 1 instead of 1,2,3 for all indexes you are showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(e){

  var mdCopy = $('.must_Duplicated').clone();

  $.each($(mdCopy).find('input'), function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).attr('name').match(/\d/g), 10);
    var startString = $(this).attr('name').split("[")[0];
    var endString = $(this).attr('name').split(".")[1];

    //increment the number
    n++;

    //rebuild the string
    $(this).attr('name', startString + "[" + n + "]." + endString);

  });

  //md_Copy now has updated inputs
  console.log(mdCopy);

});
```

This will break the string up, increment the number and then put it back together in a copy of the original div - although this gives the format

study[1].name

study[1].Middle

study[1].surname

rather than the 1,2,3 format in the question.  Hope this helps

Comment: Hi , thank you I will try your solution . 
I think i made a mistake when i wrote 1 2 3 above 
because its 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

Native Javascript:

```
function duplicateForm() {
  // get a copy of the first form which is as good as any.
  var all_instances = document.getElementsByClassName("duplicate");
  var first_instance = all_instances[0];
  var clone_instance = first_instance.cloneNode(true);

  // calculate the new index (just the number of existing instances of the form)
  var new_index = all_instances.length;

  // increment index of the study "array"
  var new_inputs = clone_instance.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
  for (var i = 0; i < new_inputs.length; i++) {
    new_inputs[i].name = new_inputs[i].name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, "[" + new_index + "]");
  }

  // put new instance where you want it
  document.body.appendChild(clone_instance);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rur36n4x/17/